# Not Applying CIFilter on video properly

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, cgaffinetransform, cifilter, avasset

[image]I Have 2 Portrait videos. one which is taken from default iphone camera and second one is record from my application using UIIMagePickerController.

when i apply cifilter on video 1 then filter apply perfectly but when i apply filter on second video then video getting zoomed half video part blurred and stretched and when i export it it should rotate.

My Code

```
AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPhotoEffectInstant"];

player.currentItem.videoComposition  = [AVVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset: asset applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest *request){
    // Clamp to avoid blurring transparent pixels at the image edges

    CIImage *source = [request.sourceImage imageByClampingToExtent];
    source = [source imageByApplyingTransform:FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform];

    [filter setValue:source forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    // Crop the blurred output to the bounds of the original image
    CIImage *output = [filter.outputImage imageByCroppingToRect:request.sourceImage.extent];

    // Provide the filter output to the composition
    [request finishWithImage:output context:nil];
}];
```

This code is not worked for second video so some change for second video
This is not proper code but i want to check its size and orientation and After changes in orientation its works fine when play in avplayer but when export it is rotated

[AVPlayer plays video composition result incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580966/avplayer-plays-video-composition-result-incorrectly)

i checked this link we both facing same issue so i changes my code according to this but still not working properly

```
AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPhotoEffectInstant"];


UIImageOrientation FirstAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
BOOL  isFirstAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform firstTransform = FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == 1.0 && firstTransform.c == -1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {
    FirstAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight;
    isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == -1.0 && firstTransform.c == 1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {
    FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft;
    isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if(firstTransform.a == 1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == 1.0)   {
    FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
}
if(firstTransform.a == -1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == -1.0) {
    FirstAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
}

player.currentItem.videoComposition = [AVVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset:asset applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest * _Nonnull request) {
    // Step 1: get the input frame image (screenshot 1)
    CIImage *sourceImage = request.sourceImage;

    // Step 2: rotate the frame
    CIFilter *transformFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTransform"];
    [transformFilter setValue:sourceImage forKey: kCIInputImageKey];
    [transformFilter setValue: [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform: firstTransform] forKey: kCIInputTransformKey];
    sourceImage = transformFilter.outputImage;
    CGRect extent = sourceImage.extent;
    CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-extent.origin.x, -extent.origin.y);
    [transformFilter setValue:sourceImage forKey: kCIInputImageKey];
    [transformFilter setValue: [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform: translation] forKey: kCIInputTransformKey];
    sourceImage = transformFilter.outputImage;

    // Step 3: apply the custom filter chosen by the user
    extent = sourceImage.extent;
    sourceImage = [sourceImage imageByClampingToExtent];
    [filter setValue:sourceImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    sourceImage = filter.outputImage;
    sourceImage = [sourceImage imageByCroppingToRect:extent];

    // make the frame the same aspect ratio as the original input frame
    // by adding empty spaces at the top and the bottom of the extent rectangle
    CGFloat newHeight = 1920 * 1920 / extent.size.height;
    CGFloat inset = (extent.size.height - newHeight) / 2;
    extent = CGRectInset(extent, 0, inset);
    sourceImage = [sourceImage imageByCroppingToRect:extent];

    // scale down to the original frame size
    CGFloat scale = 1920 / newHeight;
    CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale*3.2);
    [transformFilter setValue:sourceImage forKey: kCIInputImageKey];
    [transformFilter setValue: [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform: scaleTransform] forKey: kCIInputTransformKey];
    sourceImage = transformFilter.outputImage;

    // translate the frame to make it's origin start at (0, 0)
    CGAffineTransform translation1 = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    [transformFilter setValue:sourceImage forKey: kCIInputImageKey];
    [transformFilter setValue: [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform: translation1] forKey: kCIInputTransformKey];
    sourceImage = transformFilter.outputImage;

    // Step 4: finish processing the frame (screenshot 2)
    [request finishWithImage:sourceImage context:nil];

}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove your transform line, that cause problem to it.

Only this one :

```
source = [source imageByApplyingTransform:FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform];
```

And check. :)

```
AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPhotoEffectInstant"];

player.currentItem.videoComposition  = [AVVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset: asset applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest *request){
    // Clamp to avoid blurring transparent pixels at the image edges

    CIImage *source = [request.sourceImage imageByClampingToExtent];

    [filter setValue:source forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    // Crop the blurred output to the bounds of the original image
    CIImage *output = [filter.outputImage imageByCroppingToRect:request.sourceImage.extent];

    // Provide the filter output to the composition
    [request finishWithImage:output context:nil];
}];
```